# Run multiple laravel queue jobs at the same time using redis server and supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, redis, supervisord, laravel-artisan

I am working on queue job in Laravel v4.2 project and I have five queue worker to perform different type of jobs in queues and each worker has more than 500 jobs at the same time. For queue job I am using redis server and supervisor to process automatically. Now problem  that I am facing is that supervisor process one job at a time and another job process after completing the first queue job. Now I want to process more than one job at the same time and for this purpose I search on google and forums too but failed to find correct answer below is my command that I am running to run queue jobs through supervisor

```
command=php /home/rizwan/php/webservices/local/artisan queue:listen --queue=notificationQueue,lowQueue --tries=1
command=php /home/rizwan/php/Fayvo/favyo_webservices/local/artisan queue:listen --tries=1
```

if I remove priority param from command then queue jobs does not process which is wrong and if I add it then it process notificationQueue jobs first and then lowQueue jobs after processing all the jobs of notificationQueue jobs but I want to process both jobs at same time.

supervisor configuration

```
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs = 4
process_name = %(program_name)s%(process_num)s
user=rizwan
```